# Transform complex JSON into VB.net- Class

Tags: json, vb.net

We have the following problem, the JSON below is dynamically generated for each of our users after logging in to our website using php. 
Because we access with a self-developed Windows desktop program on the same database, we need to process the JSON also the part of VB. 
We are using the VB-board tools (should so remain, at best)
So far we have failed to define a suitable VB class that receives the JSON.
In one-dimensional JSON it works with List Of (own object) very well, but here we haven´t found a suitable definition yet.

JSON (reduced to the number of elements present):

```
{
        "id": "639C",
        "admin": "0",
        "blacklist": [
            {
                "id": "4CE5",
                "name": "DEMO",
                "rechte": []
            },
            {
                "id": "EC81",
                "name": "ENTWICKLUNG",
                "rechte": [
                    {
                        "id": "001C",
                        "sichtbar": "-1",
                        "neu": "0",
                        "loeschen": "0",
                        "bearbeiten": "-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0068",
                        "sichtbar": "-1",
                        "neu": "0",
                        "loeschen": "0",
                        "bearbeiten": "-1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

VB-Class (already changed a thousand times):

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.IO

<DataContract()> _
Public Class myLoginResponse

    Private _Id As String
    Private _Admin As String
    Private _myMandanten As myMandanten(Of myBlacklist(Of myRecht))

    <DataMember(Name:="id")> _
    Public Property Id() As String
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(Name:="admin")> _
    Public Property Admin() As String
        Get
            Return _Admin
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Admin = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property myMandanten() As myMandanten(Of myBlacklist(Of myRecht))
        Get
            Return _myMandanten
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As myMandanten(Of myBlacklist(Of myRecht)))
            _myMandanten = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<DataContract()> _
Public Class myMandanten(Of T)

    Inherits List(Of T)

    Private _myBlacklist As myBlacklist(Of myRecht)

    Public Property myBlacklist() As myBlacklist(Of myRecht)
        Get
            Return _myBlacklist
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As myBlacklist(Of myRecht))
            _myBlacklist = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<DataContract()> _
Public Class myBlacklist(Of T)

    Inherits List(Of myRecht)

    Private _Id As String
    Private _Name As String

    <DataMember(Name:="id")> _
    Public Property Id() As String
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(Name:="name")> _
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<DataContract()> _
Public Class myRecht
    Private _Id As String
    Private _Sichtbar As Boolean
    Private _Neu As Boolean
    Private _Loeschen As Boolean
    Private _Bearbeiten As Boolean

    <DataMember(Name:="id")> _
    Public Property Id() As String
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(Name:="sichtbar")> _
    Public Property Sichtbar() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Sichtbar
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Sichtbar = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(Name:="neu")> _
    Public Property Neu() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Neu
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Neu = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(Name:="loeschen")> _
    Public Property Loeschen() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Loeschen
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Loeschen = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(Name:="bearbeiten")> _
    Public Property Bearbeiten() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Bearbeiten
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Bearbeiten = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Use Visual Studio and *Edit* -> *Paste Special* -> *Paste JSON As Classes*

Comment: I assume you've looked at NewtonSoft.JSON.

Konrad - in what VS version/context does that Paste Special work?

Comment: In [VS 2012 with Web Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx) and in VS 2013 by default I believe.